# std::locale constructor throws an exception in a program compiled with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, locale

This code works in MSVC (2022) and throws a runtime error in MinGW (x86_64-w64-mingw32 gcc-12.2.0):

```
#include <locale>
int main() 
{
    std::locale l("en_US.utf8");
}
```

The error is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

I have tried many different locale names including `""`, `"en_US"`, and `"English"`. All of them work with MSVC and fail with MinGW. The only ones that work in MinGW are `"C"` and `"POSIX"` (no `"C.utf8"` or any other variant).

What gives? Isn't MinGW supposed to use the MSVC runtime? How can I make it work?

Comment: What effects from an utf8 locale do you need?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed. Kids these days! Back in my day we used EBCDIC, in the snow, both ways.  And we liked it. And now these spoiled brats want to use their own language to print stuff on the screen, and they don't want, as they're saying, to "jump through hoops" to do that. Snowflakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `"C"` and `"POSIX"` locales are supported under MinGW port of GCC and libstdc++.

The implementation of `std::locale::locale` in libstdc++ has special treatment for these two locale names. All others are deferred to one of the platform-specific implementations, called "underlying locale models" in libstdc++ source. There are several of those, called `darwin`, `ieee_1003.1-2001`, `vxworks`, `dragonfly`, `gnu`, `newlib`, and lastly `generic` The latter is a fallback that only supports the `"C"` locale.

`generic` is the model that is selected when GCC is configured on Windows. As a result, `std::locale::locale` doesn't call any platform function that is able to create a locale.

This can be fixed by fixing either libstdc++ or MinGW. libstdc++ could introduce a new locale model that works directly with MSVCRT `_create_locale` and friends. On the other hand, MinGW could implement a shim that would translate between native Windows locales and one of the models supported by libstdc++.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of fixing this in users' programs.