# An error happens when using locale() in C++ MinGw(g++)

Tags: c++, locale

When I tried to run the following code on VScode, an error always happened.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

```
    #include <locale>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        locale eng("en_US.UTF-8"); // use locale character
        wcin.imbue(eng);           // use locale object
        wcout.imbue(eng);
        wstring s;
        wchar_t wc = L'.';
        while (getline(wcin, s, wc))
        {
            wcout << s << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Here's the locale information:

```
D:\Projects\Cpp_Programs\book>locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL=
```

I've tried to change locale eng("en_US"), locale eng("en_UK")....But always failed with the same error information.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: MinGW does not support any locales except "C".

Comment: Support for internationalization in C++ is so very poor that I think it's easier to do whatever it is that you want to do yourself (or buy in a third party library). It seems you want to read UTF-8 and convert to wide characters. If you wrote that conversion yourself it would be maybe 30 lines of code. It's not so hard to do. It's even possible to do via the locale/facet API in the standard library if that's what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::locale constructor throws an exception in a program compiled with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75426537/stdlocale-constructor-throws-an-exception-in-a-program-compiled-with-mingw) _"...Only "C" and "POSIX" locales are supported under MinGW port of GCC and libstdc++...."_

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for your suggestion. I'm new here, and it's my first time asking a question. I've replaced the image with text format.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the quote link. it seems to be the reason that MinGW lacks support for locales. I'll try to fix it in other ways.

Comment: What exactly do you want to fix? You don't need to deal with locales in order to read and write Unicode *as wide characters* to/from the console, but you might need to `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);`.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, it works. But I cannot use `cout<<"abc"<<endl;` to print normal characters anymore before changing `_setmode` back.

Comment: That's right, you can't. Once on wcout, always on wcout. Use `wcout << L"abc"`.