Dev C++ Locale only working while using system's locale and not when specifing name
When using setlocale() to change the locale of the program to Italian, the code works as expected only when using setlocale(LC_ALL, "") and not when using setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT").
I am currently using Dev C++ with its default compiler and my OS is windows 10.
I tried checking the returned value of setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT") and it returned NULL.
I tried to use different locale names in case I made a mistake while looking up the locale, I tried using "it_IT" and "it" and I tried putting .utf8 at the end of both versions of the locale name.
The specific use case is a printf with an è inside it. When the code works as expected I get an è in the output, and when it doesn't I get what I think is a Greek character.
Minimum reproducible example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("è");
    return 0;
}

this code works as expected and gives "è" as output
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT");
    printf("è");
    return 0;
}

this code doesn't work as expected and gives "Þ" as output (the same thing happens with the other values for the name of the locale i mentioned before). Not setting the locale also gives the same result

Is the locale installed at your target platform? Which platform (OS, etc) is it?

the locale is installed on the platform I am running the code on. As I mentioned in the question I am currently using a windows machine, so that would be the OS

Small point: did you try "it"?

i'll edit the question since i forgot i tried it, but i did and it didn't work

the specific case is a printf with an "è" inside it.  When the code works as expected i get an "è" in the output, while when it doesn't i get what I think is a greek character

Here is a similar question but about C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75426537/stdlocale-constructor-throws-an-exception-in-a-program-compiled-with-mingw Not sure if it is applicable to C.

I don't think it is applicable since when using "" instead of a specific locale name it does print the è, and the è is in neither the POSIX and the C locale

Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem. And post the inputs, the expected output and the actual output.

"The specific use case is a printf with an è inside it" That's a different problem, related to character encoding. Your codepage must support the "è" and you must send the appropriate bit pattern to the OS. Forget about the locale (the "it-IT" part is unrelated to your problem and the "utf-8"  part is just for telling your program which codepage is selected). If the "è" is part of a literal, your code may be interpreted as encoded in a different codepage. If you show as your source code, we could try an answer.

added the example

What happens when you don't even set the locale? Does it depend on the terminal settings?

not setting the locale gives the same result as setting it to "it-IT"

...because my Windows console is configured for code page: 65001 and it handles (some of) UTF-8 anyway.

What is the encoding of the source file? What is the codepage of the terminal?

I don't think i changed any settings for my terminal

@n.m.couldbeanAI i am pretty new at this so idk what you mean, i might take a while to answer your question because i have to look that up

codepage of the terminal is 850 i think, Checking the character set it should support the è character

What is the actual value of "è" that you output? Is it a multi-byte UTF-8 character, or is it one of the old-fashioned non-ASCII characters in the range 128-255? When I redirect printf("è"); to a file (without any locale setting), there are two bytes; c3 a8. Does your text editor that you code with handle UTF-8?

@WeatherVane when doing sizeof("è") i get that the size is 2 bytes so i am guessing an UTF-8 rather than an ASCII character

That is a string, which has a nul terminator. I suggest you redirect the output to a file, and inspect it with a hex editor.

wait you are right, let me check again

@WeatherVane the 'è' char's size seems to be 1 byte

Aside: I use Notepad++ for text and code editing, which supports UTF-8.

my course suggests I use Dev C++ so I'd rather stick with that right now

Then see it it can be enabled for UTF-8. Your "è" seems to be obsolete character encoding.

checking online it seems that dev c++ does not support UTF-8 and since it has not been updated since 2016 i doubt that will change

AFAIK the previous DEV-C++ was inactive since 2005, and the revived 2020 version Embarcadero Dev-C++ introduced UTF-8 text encoding.

i'll check embarcadero out and see if using it solves the issue

Hmm does your course say both use Dev-C++ and use non-ASCII characters?

using non ACII characters is just a consequence of being Italian, è is the equivalent of "is" so in any string where i would use that verb i have a non ASCII character

If you have a choice, just use English in this course. Why make your life harder than it needs to be? If they don't require you to output Italian, nor teach you how to, don't do that. If you want to anyway, on Windows it's usually made with wide characters/strings these days. Using UTF-8 requires you to change the code page, which could be a problem if you need other people to run your program—why would they want to change their codepage? Same thing about legacy 8-bit code pages.

@DrGMark7, what is the return value of setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT");?

in Windows you should use it_IT.UTF-8 locale and set the source as well as all compiler options to UTF-8

Premise: I am dumb. 
The issue was that the command prompt opened by Dev c++ (both the older and the newer version) was not using the correct encoding, and as such the output of the program was wrong. moving to codepage 65001 in the command prompt and executing the code from there fixed the issue
edit: while the answer above this worked, the issue was actually in the name of the locale. For some reason, it_IT or variations of it was not accepted as a locale, but Italian_Italy was
adding some code, the following code works:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Italian_Italy");
    print("è");
    return 0;
}

Second edit:
After researching a bit, the issue was also caused by Dev C++ using win32 locale names, meaning it_IT would not be a valid locale name, but Italian_Italy would. When using the embarcadero version of Dev C++, Unicode encoding is supported, but the locale name is still with win32 standard. This means it_IT.UTF8 is not a valid locale, but Italian_Italy.1252 is.
Another thing to add is that older Dev C++ still uses a 1 byte char for the "è", so a printf is enough to print it, but embarcadero can use the 2 byte version, meaning that wprintf needs to be used

One more time: you had an incompatibility between your source file encoding (for what you say now, it was actually UTF-8) and your active code page (yes, the one set by "chcp" at a command prompt). Code page 65001 is UTF-8. (Usual code pages were single-bit, but this one is an exception.) By the way, in Windows (not in Unix/Linux) you can also change your active code page using setlocale().

i'll see if i can fix it changing the active code page, but the issue stayed when running the code through dev c++ even when switching codepage, while it was solved after changing codepage when running it directly through the command prompt

You said your first setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT") returned NULL. This means it failed (I don't really know why, but it was probably because of a misspelled string). When this happens, the "C" locale is used, and it doesn't allow for "international" characters. On the other hand, your setlocale(LC_ALL, "") (according to Microsoft documentation) "Sets the locale to the default, which is the user-default ANSI code page obtained from the operating system."

oh i didnt see that part about it being ANSI when using "",  could it be that it_IT only works as a locale name when it is UTF-8? Because if that's the case then the issue would be me not knowing there are different names when using ANSI

I think "it-IT" just failed, leaving a 7-bit "C" (no "international") code page active. Beware that Microsoft calls "ANSI" to all the "classic" 8-bit code pages, or "extended ASCII" sets, including all ISO-8859 variants, CP850, CP860, Microsoft's own 1252, etc. All of these "ANSI pages" support "international" characters (at least for Latin and European languages), but with many different actual encodings.

from what I understand it-IT is not an ANSI locale, and the correct ANSI locale would indeed be Italian_Italy, while it-IT would be used for UTF-8 encoding with it-IT.utf8, though I am not sure. Since dev c++ does not support utf8, it-IT.utf8 would fail, making the locale the default "C"

The locale sets several things, including the preferred language for messages, the format for dates, the comma separator character, etc. The last part is the character set, which not only describes a set of available characters (an extended "alphabet") but also an encoding (a bit pattern representing each character). In Windows, this concept is directly associated with a "code page". Texts in Italian may use any character set that includes the accentuated letters, etc. This may be any 8-bit "extended ASCII" set (called "ANSI" by Microsoft), UTF-8 (one to four bytes per character), UTF-16, etc.

As been said, you have a conflict between the encoding of your C source file (which is applied to the included literals) and the encoding supported (and activated) by your OS (in Windows, this is the "codepage").
I'm not sure about the relationship between this and the "it-IT" locale, and I'm not being able to reproduce the problem at all times. But you may try something like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "it-IT.utf8");
    printf("è");
    return 0;
}

But saving your source file with UTF8 encoding. (If you're using Visual Studio Code, look for the encoding tag in the bottom toolbar. See Change the encoding of a file in Visual Studio Code).
Note. If you want to use codepage 850, set it instead of utf8 (both, in the setlocale() and as the source file encoding).

I am currently using Dev C++. i already tried adding .utf8 at the end and it did not change the output

Sorry! For some reason, I failed to read that line in your question :). Anyway, for code literals to be understood, you have to save your source file using the target encoding (utf8, codepage 850, etc).

after checking with another person in the comments it seems to be a Dev C++ issue, as it is using a 1 byte è rather than the UTF-8 2 byte è for whatever reason

Ok, but you don't really need to use UTF-8. You can use any encoding that matches your codepage (which may be an 8-bit codepage, like ISO-8859-1, CP 860, etc). Or viceversa: change your codepage according to the encoding of your source file. Or don't use literals but an explicit '\x8a' (for the 'è' in CP 860). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_860.
